# The argument query in the GET function in R is showing "%2C" instead of ","

Tags: r, get, httr

I'm trying to use the `GET` function, in the R package `httr`, to get info from a web page like:
  http://fake.web.com/fruit?type=APPLE,GREEN&number=2
so I´m ussing the code:

```
resp <- GET("http://fake.web.com/fruit", query = list(type = "APPLE,GREEN", number = 2))
```

But when I check the url of `resp` I'm getting:

http://fake.web.com/fruit?type=APPLE%2CGREEN&number=2  instead of

http://fake.web.com/fruit?type=APPLE,GREEN&number=2

How can I solve this?